# Convert XML to PDF with Oxygen

Tags: java, xml, pdf, oxygenxml

I convert HTML to XML through Herold. After transfom XML file to PDF with Oxygen Author, Developer or Editor it throws many errors. I try change settings before tranform, change XSLT or Transfomer, but it doesn't help me. Do you have any idea?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <info>
    <title>11 obrovských prešľapov návrhu loga - Zajtra.sk</title>
  </info>
  <para><anchor xml:id="top" xreflabel=""/></para>
  <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/"><emphasis role="bold">Zajtra.sk</emphasis></link></para>
  <para>spájame</para>
  <para>slovenskú</para>
  <para>IT komunitusleduj Zajtra.sk</para>
  <para><link xl:href="http://www.facebook.com/zajtrask/">Facebook</link> · <link xl:href="http://www.twitter.com/zajtrask/">Twitter</link> · <link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/rss/zajtra.rss"><emphasis role="bold">RSS</emphasis></link> pridaj sa</para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Registrácia</emphasis> · <link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/site/login">Login</link>    <!--
search
-->
<itemizedlist><listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/">Začiatok</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem condition="active">
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn">Dizajn</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/marketing">Marketing</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/programovanie">Programovanie</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/rozhovory">Rozhovory</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/technologie">Technológie</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/zivot">Život</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/ludia">Ľudia</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/portfolia">Portfóliá</link></para>
      </listitem>
</itemizedlist>    <!--
menu
-->
    <!--
header
-->
<anchor xml:id="content"/><itemizedlist><listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn/fotografie">Fotografie</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem condition="active">
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn/grafika">Grafika</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn/loga">Logá</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn/photoshop">Photoshop</link></para>
      </listitem>
<listitem>
        <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn/serialy">Seriály</link></para>
      </listitem>
</itemizedlist><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/ludia/800/muro">Muro</link> 26.11.2011<bridgehead remap="h1">11 obrovských prešľapov návrhu loga</bridgehead> Galéria dizajnérskych nepodarkov, ktoré pobavili celý svet.</para>
  <para>Logo spoločnosti je v očiach verejnosti jedným zo základných pilierov firemnej identity. No vytvorenie takéhoto loga nie je vôbec jednoduché. Malo by v sebe skĺbiť podstatu spoločnosti, jej základné hodnoty a princípy. Trik je však v tom, vytvoriť logo jednoduché, ale jedinečne také, čo okamžite upúta pozornosť, vyvolá emóciu a ostane v pamäti. </para>
  <para>Nie každé logo, ktoré však upúta pozornosť, vyvolá emóciu a ostane v pamäti, je skvelým a unikátnym dizajnérskym počinom. Niekedy v ňom len ostatní vidia niečo, čo si spoločnosť pri schvaľovaní svojho kľúčového identifikačného prvku jednoducho nevšimla.</para>
  <para>Určite mi dáte za pravdu, že raz vidieť je lepšie, ako stokrát počuť. Tu je preto galéria 11 obrovských dizajnérskych prešľapov. Dobre sa bavte:)</para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Dough boy&apos;s pizza</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/dough-bo.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/dough-bo.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://my.opera.com/Zaphira/blog/badly-designed-logos</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Junior Jazz Dance Classes</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/4dfc703c.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/4dfc703c.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para> Uznávam, na prvý pohľad sa toto logo tvári celkom nevinne, no keď sa naňho zahľadíte o sekundu dlhšie, odhalíte nečakané prekvapenie.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://ginva.com/2011/02/16-logo-design-fail/</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">CatWear</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/logo-cat.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/logo-cat.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://www.boredpanda.com/worst-logo-fails-ever/</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">OGC logo</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/ogc-logo.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/ogc-logo.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para>Trocha rotácie a voilà.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://irfanrasyid.blogspot.com/2010/02/20-epic-logo-fails.html</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Mont-Sat</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/logo-des.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/logo-des.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para>Satelit s veľkou anténou.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://www.demilked.com/worst-logo-design-fails/</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Catholic Church’s Archdiocesan Youth Commission</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/worst000.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/worst000.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://www.boredpanda.com/worst-logo-fails-ever/</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Arlington Pediatric Center</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/Arlingto.png" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/Arlingto.png" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://unreasonablydangerousonionrings.blogspot.com/2011/04/logo-design-must-be-harder-than-i.html</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Computer Doctors</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/computer.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/computer.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para>Logo spolo4nosti Computer Doctors je jasným príkladom toho, ako prehnaná snaha o kreativitu, môže byť v konečnom dôsledku dosť na škodu. A pritom stačilo napísať obyčajné U.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://funoholic.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/logos-gone-wild/</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Mega Flicks</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/megaflic.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/megaflic.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para>Niekedy je rozdiel medzi dobrým a zlým logom len otázkou výberu vhodného fontu. Ako mohol toto majiteľ prehliadnuť mi je záhadou.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://www.andrewkeir.com/15-logo-design-disasters/</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">The Institute of Oriental Studies</emphasis></para>
  <para><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
        <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/Brazilia.gif" scalefit="1"/>
      </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
        <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/Brazilia.gif" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></para>
  <para><emphasis>Zdroj:http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Federal_University_of_Santa_Catarina,_Brazil</emphasis></para>
  <para><emphasis role="bold">Pýtate sa kde je jedenáste logo?</emphasis> Jedenáste miesto v tejto galérií plnej skvostov som nechal pre vás. Ak ste sa niekedy stretli s logom, ktoré na druhý pohľad nápadne pripomínalo niečo, čo jeho autor určite nezamýšľal, pošlite linku cez sekciu komentárov. </para>
  <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/ludia/800/muro"><inlinemediaobject><imageobject role="html">
          <imagedata fileref=".//Ahoj_files/800_th15.jpg" scalefit="1"/>
        </imageobject>
<imageobject role="fo">
          <imagedata contentdepth="100%" fileref=".//Ahoj_files/800_th15.jpg" scalefit="1" width="100%"/>
        </imageobject>
</inlinemediaobject></link></para>
  <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/ludia/800/muro"><emphasis role="bold">Muro</emphasis></link></para>
  <para>Muro píše na stránke <link xl:href="http://www.bizbuzz.sk/"><emphasis role="bold">BizBuzz.sk</emphasis></link>. Zaujímajú ho sociálne siete, online marketing, kreatívna reklama a ich miesto v dnešnom svete. Najdeš ho aj na <link xl:href="http://twitter.com/BizBuzzsk">Twitteri</link> či <link xl:href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/BizBuzzsk/263928330318009">Facebooku</link>.</para>
   <anchor xml:id="sharebuttons"/>
  <!--
toto sa nacita javascriptom az po nacitani stranky, aby to nezdrzovalo
-->
  <para><anchor xml:id="komentare" xreflabel=""/></para>
  <section remap="h2">
    <title>13 komentárov k článku:</title>
    <para> Zaregistruj sa cez <link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/site/register"><emphasis role="bold">bezplatnú registráciu</emphasis></link> alebo použi <link xl:href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=189941867727355&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zajtra.sk%2Fsite%2Ffblogin&amp;scope=email,user_birthday,user_website"><emphasis role="bold">login cez Facebook</emphasis> (FB Connect)</link></para>
    <para>Prihlás sa tu, ak už máš profil na Zajtra.sk: </para>
    <anchor xml:id="login-form"/>
    <anchor condition="login" xml:id="LoginForm_username"/>
    <anchor condition="login" xml:id="LoginForm_password"/>
      <!--
pagination
-->
    <!--
content
-->
    <anchor xml:id="sidebar"/>
    <!--
sidebar
-->
    <para><link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/">Zajtra.sk</link></para>
    <para> &gt; <link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn">Dizajn</link> &gt; <link xl:href="http://www.zajtra.sk/dizajn/grafika">Grafika</link> &gt; 11 obrovských prešľapov návrhu loga      <!--
article
-->
</para>
  </section>
</article>
```

and Errors

```
System ID: C:\Program Files (x86)\Herold\bin\ahoj12345.xml
Scenario: Docbook PDF duplicate
XML file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Herold\bin\ahoj12345.xml
XSL file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Oxygen XML Editor 13\frameworks\docbook\xsl\fo\profile-docbook.xsl
Engine name: Apache FOP
Severity: error
Description: The process 'Apache FOP' ended with code: 1.
The error was: 
ERROR - Exception
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See position 4:-1)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandlerFOP.transformTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandlerFOP.renderTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:174)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:205)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See position 4:-1)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.handleSAXException(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.startContent(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.startContent(NamespaceReducer.java:197)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.startElement(ReceivingContentHandler.java:351)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:400)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:154)
    at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:35)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See position 4:-1)
    at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(ValidationExceptionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(EventExceptionManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(DefaultEventBroadcaster.java:175)
    at $Proxy1.invalidChild(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:534)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:517)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.Flow.validateChildNode(Flow.java:103)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:171)
    ... 21 more

---------

net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See position 4:-1)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.handleSAXException(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.startContent(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.startContent(NamespaceReducer.java:197)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.startElement(ReceivingContentHandler.java:351)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:400)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:154)
    at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:35)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandlerFOP.transformTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandlerFOP.renderTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:174)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:205)
Caused by: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See position 4:-1)
    at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(ValidationExceptionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(EventExceptionManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(DefaultEventBroadcaster.java:175)
    at $Proxy1.invalidChild(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:534)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:517)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.Flow.validateChildNode(Flow.java:103)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:171)
    ... 21 more
---------
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}inline" is not a valid child of "fo:flow"! (See position 4:-1)
    at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(ValidationExceptionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(EventExceptionManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(DefaultEventBroadcaster.java:175)
    at $Proxy1.invalidChild(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:534)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:517)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.Flow.validateChildNode(Flow.java:103)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:171)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.startContent(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.startContent(NamespaceReducer.java:197)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.startElement(ReceivingContentHandler.java:351)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:400)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:154)
    at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:35)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandlerFOP.transformTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandlerFOP.renderTo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:174)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:205)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your Docbook 5 XML document has an anchor at some point:

which generates an invalid XSL-FO document.
I think you should report this problem to the Docbook users list.
In the meantime you can remove the anchor, it does not seem to be really referenced anywhere (or move it in a paragraph).

Regards,
Radu

Radu Coravu
  XML Editor, Schema Editor and XSLT Editor/Debugger
http://www.oxygenxml.com